# Using SaveAs Function, but periods change the fileformat

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, file-format, save-as

I open an Excel file, fill some cells and then save it in a new folder.

The generated files include today's date that includes periods.

If the filename for example is "Template_Name_01.01.2022" the fileformat changes to .2022

```vb
Dim OriginalFileName As String
fileName = "Template_" & Nz(rs!Street, "Address") & "_" & Date
    
OriginalFileName = fileName
Dim fileNumber As Integer
fileNumber = 1

Do Until nameFree = True
    
    nameCheck = Dir("G:\Argus\_Deal Tracker 3.0\Deals_Inv Mgmt\" & fileName)
    
    If nameCheck = "" Then
        xlBook.SaveAs fileName:="G:\Argus\_Deal Tracker 3.0\Deals_Inv Mgmt\" & fileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLStrictWorkbook
        nameFree = True
    Else
        fileName = OriginalFileName
        fileName = fileName & " (" & fileNumber & ")"
        fileNumber = fileNumber + 1
    End If

Loop
```

Even though I determine the fileFormat it saves the file as .2022

[Saved files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdb24.png)

If I add an ".xlsx" extension to the filename it works for me but not on other PCs, I am guessing it is because they have file extensions hidden.

If they run the function they get this error.
[image]

Is there a way to prevent the file format changing if periods appear in the name?

Comment: You should add the extension to the filename - Excel *might* guess your intention correctly, it might not. Why risk it? As for the error other users are getting - that should probably be raised as a separate question once you've attempted to debug that issue yourself.

Comment: Why would excel guess the fileformat if I determine it with the fileFormat:= function.

Comment: And I dont know how i would debug that error as it only highlights the save as code. I am just guessing it apperas because of the file extension, because I have no other clue.

Comment: The date is formatted with periods. But even if not the streetname could always contain a period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to format the `Date` to remove the forward slashes `/` from the file name as they're not allowed. You also need to supply the file extension in the path.

So, change this:

```
fileName = "Template_" & Nz(rs!Street, "Address") & "_" & Date
```

to this:

```
fileName = "Template_" & Nz(rs!Street, "Address") & "_" & Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy") & ".xlsx" 'change to your extension
```

Comment: Thanks that was the reason, seems like my access had a different date format then other useres.

Comment: *locale* differences perhaps?

Comment: Probably, I have a weird mix of german and englissh settings some microsoft apps are in english others are in german.

Answer (score 0):

Performing the Save As from script, you have to contruct the whole filename, including the extension.

Basically you have to add something like:

```
fileName = "Template_" & Nz(rs!Street, "Address") & "_" & Date & ".csv"
```

Comment: As I stated, I already did that, but that leads to an error message on other users PC's

Comment: My fault, sorry! I think if the combo FileFormat/extension could be incorrect. Try using FileFormat:=xlCSV. Alternatively try FileFormat:=51 for and ".xlsx" extension string.

Comment: How do you get the impression that the OP wants to deal with CSV files?

Comment: Thats right it needs to be xlsx as it is a whole workbook.

Comment: I tried the fileFormat:=51 and the same error appears. The weird thing is that it works for me but not for other useres.

Comment: I have no more ideas... I don't know if could be useful, but this is the sequence I use to perform a SaveAs: 
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objSheet.SaveAs FileName:=PathName & "\" & FileName, FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False
objWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing